# Problema al crear una Aplicación web ASP.NET (.NET Framework), error Devuelto error HRESULT E_FAIL de una llamada a un componente COM

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2022

estoy trabajando el servidor api de mi aplicación en asp.net C#, con .net framework en Visual Studio 2022, pero por alguna razon no me permite crear el proyecto ya que me bota el error
**Devuelto error HRESULT E_FAIL de una llamada a un componente
COM.**
y por lo tanto el proyecto no se crea o se crea pero se crea vacio, adjunto evidencia de lo que sucede
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero alguien tenga una solucion a este error ya que no me permite avanzar con mi trabajo y me estoy quedando estancado